# How to get javascript to load another html file?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet, so that when you click on it, it will load example.com/yourdata.php in a div box.

How can I make it get the data from example.com?

IFRAME? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have issues with creating a bookmarklet within another page that grabs data from a different domain (to load into a `<div />` using Ajax).

Your best option is probably to insert an IFrame with the content as the source of the page.

If you want to do this as a very basic lightbox, you could do something like this:

```
(function() {

    var iFrame = document.createElement('IFRAME');

    iFrame.src = 'http://google.com';
    iFrame.style.cssText = 'display: block; position:absolute; ' 
                         + 'top: 10%; left: 25%; width: 50%; height: 50%';

    document.body.insertBefore(iFrame, document.body.firstChild); 

})();
```

And here is the same code in bookmarklet format:

```
javascript: (function() { var iFrame = document.createElement('IFRAME'); iFrame.src = 'http://google.com'; iFrame.style.cssText = 'display: block; position:absolute; top: 10%; left: 25%; width: 50%; height: 50%'; document.body.insertBefore(iFrame, document.body.firstChild); })();
```

You could also style this a lot more if you wanted something pretty. This is just a basic example of what is possible. As another person said, it would be easiest to make it pretty by loading jQuery using an Ajax request, but that is a little more involved.

Answer (score 1):

Do an AJAX call directly in your bookmarklet, and then set the innerHTML of your div to the returned content. Not sure if there are security restrictions on this or not.

Edit: You don't want to use JQuery, as you can't easily load a javascript library from a bookmarklet. (Although maybe you could get it via AJAX and then eval it...)

You need to do a classic [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Some [more info here](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).

Comment: how? I don't have much experience with Jquery. also will it be able to load a file from another server? i.e. if I am on cnn.com, will my bookmarklet be able to load my file from example.com?

Answer (score 1):

With **[The Dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org)** you can use **[dijit.layout.ContentPane](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit/layout/content-pane)** or **[dojox.layout.ContentPane](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-5-dojox/dojox-layout)** to do exactly what you want in one single div.
The difference between dijit.layout.ContentPane and dojox.layout.ContentPane is that you can run inline javascript inside the dojox.layout.ContentPane.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the domain restriction by making a php function on my server that outputs a page on another domain. that way, javascript thinks it is in the same domain when I do an ajax.updater call.

$sSrcPage = $_REQUEST['SrcPage'];

echo file_get_contents($sSrcPage, 0);